# Entity Framework - Does it matter which objects create the relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Assuming I have a database that links patients to doctors with three tables. The third table being a relationship table.

```
DoctorId    DoctorName
------------------------
1           Dr. Jones
2           Dr. Smith

PatientId   PatientName
------------------------
1           Tom Jones
2           Jerry Lewis

DoctorID    PatientID
------------------------
1           1
2           1
2           2
```

With the Entity Framework I might do something like the following ...

**Example #1**

```
using (var dbContext = New MyAppDBConectContainer())
{
  var patient1 = new Patient {PatientName = "Tom Jones"};
  var doctor1 = new Doctor {DoctorName = "Dr. Jones"};
  doctor1.Patients.Add(patient1);
  dbContext.Doctors.Add(doctor1);
  dbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**Example #2**

```
using (var dbContext = New MyAppDBConectContainer())
{
  var doctor1 = new Doctor {DoctorName = "Dr. Smith"};
  var patient1 = new Patient {PatientName = "Jerry Lewis"};
  patient1.Doctors.Add(doctor1);
  dbContext.Patients.Add(patient1);
  dbContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Does it matter if you add the patient to the doctor as in Example #1 or if you add the doctor to the patient as in Example #2? Will the relationships be preserved?

Comment: Did either of the answers here answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've set up an ICollection of Patients on the Doctors entity and an ICollection of Doctors on the Patients entity, then the many-to-many relationship is inferred by Entity Framework and both scenarios will result in the same entries in the doctors, patients, and junction tables.

If you need more control over the database tables that are created, such as their names and keys, you can use the `HasMany()`, `WithMany()`, and `Map()` methods of the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In both cases yes, the relationships will be preserved.